Issue in aligning stat_cor r-value and p-value displayed on two lines in R
I am using stat_cor with ggplot to add r-value and p-value to a scatter plot. I have used label.sep = "\n" to display the r-value and p-value on two lines. However the labels are not aligned properly and I am unable to left align the labels. I tried using hjust but it doesn't seem to work.
Here's the data
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(3.24792751344359, 11.6254805504711, 9.85096815098244, 
7.62570884306446, 4.6724253419715, 5.65821148275179, 14.4494388579437, 
2.16992500144231, 3.85798099512757, 15.4013962116234, 7.38801728534513, 
4.04439411935845, 7.10328780841202, 9.38909352190447, 9.87113518424304, 
12.751439451538, 3.95419631038688, 8.44914864537544, 12.8222720641578, 
9.65731844958129, 8.78626962764847, 7.94544383637791, 6.67948009950545, 
11.2243032093734, 9.46454575033394, 3.52356195605701, 4.49185309632967, 
11.7950249839614, 4.7279204545632, 6.876516946565, 9.59339112279174, 
11.1029598859101, 3.75488750216347, 8.35974956032233, 7.14465824283188, 
8.52160043972373, 5.65821148275179, 4.49185309632967, 3.85798099512757, 
10.8730595476615, 7.04984854945056, 6.21916852046216, 6.34872815423108, 
9.66977088852552, 15.1287394887056, 10.9833499276765, 4.93073733756289, 
7.2807707701306, 3.08746284125034, 8.82495874052852, 6.53138146051631, 
8.71252700043982, 13.7365604837545, 7.34429590791582, 12.4371018289084, 
3.24792751344359, 4.49185309632967, 4.7279204545632, 2.4594316186373, 
7.65463602852797, 4.88264304936184, 13.3752431107337, 5.4757334309664, 
4.49185309632967, 7.56605403817109, 6.66533591718518, 7.14465824283188, 
7.21431912080077, 8.38154295118458, 10.4120405145517, 5.14974711950468, 
14.717435454024, 12.9335984552372, 6.07681559705083, 8.05799172275918, 
10.4424251933316, 1.32192809488736, 8.62753388447279, 11.1147183891884, 
9.17866485100647, 9.54978466794786, 2.90689059560852, 5.62935662007961, 
5.06608919045777, 5.06608919045777, 3.52356195605701, 5.18982455888002, 
10.0409745988173, 14.2054496369478, 5.89481776330794, 11.3909750061555, 
14.4876202472075, 6.31288295528436, 10.1286388128526, 7.47167521439204, 
10.9155059622319, 7.3264294871223, 3.75488750216347, 8.49385544924082, 
-1), B = c(14.3127766206581, 14.4475675741951, 14.0405893950661, 
12.9728900634355, 13.8401386381809, 13.9348426545031, 14.0350997792022, 
13.7983199091531, 12.429799009167, 13.7326444284916, 13.5774878375881, 
14.1097082484888, 13.8667476715049, 14.041530822723, 14.2691632137112, 
13.540915056731, 13.7404659380353, 14.0689042060648, 14.3322114183684, 
13.5738246735046, 14.7685720383286, 13.760252139086, 12.9358096237511, 
13.6779948548276, 13.2124203878783, 12.7894317561295, 12.5645067843387, 
13.2555449905389, 13.9070314769172, 13.2381807936996, 13.1269464072255, 
13.7651306721844, 13.0182871274371, 14.9231185320901, 13.4296028886726, 
13.1441005563635, 12.7558264511331, 13.9863309334321, 13.3964040956219, 
14.1236768648636, 13.8001415579333, 13.0215872981245, 13.3918477190335, 
13.2864855672956, 13.1608956144507, 13.9778612496769, 14.2483352900365, 
13.3115354705716, 14.1847591417854, 14.0328636422936, 13.922445032087, 
13.9193754670122, 14.1792482216554, 14.1501836084154, 13.9839288136058, 
12.9035994534655, 13.771025140805, 14.0912287527363, 13.8237155308271, 
14.0047032739544, 13.8973255233125, 13.9361318028622, 13.7190144075454, 
14.1789371199985, 12.9471803166342, 13.550205673278, 13.9818794039634, 
14.0891607874707, 13.8560850466602, 14.2923575846826, 13.3177658951147, 
13.6720385382353, 13.9022337777197, 13.6913618610263, 12.9150390555186, 
14.0970033353301, 14.0115330268357, 13.2674450883881, 14.1581757415753, 
14.1520074961942, 14.175120670275, 13.8670373693052, 13.7511778994712, 
13.1295245193378, 13.6348677587679, 13.3826915668966, 13.1415483835874, 
13.7944666359748, 13.9242093993111, 13.8643312582358, 13.5818478602248, 
13.4147512917602, 13.6018288106901, 13.791722516366, 12.8720014654425, 
12.9857530107518, 13.4543635604993, 13.1279137392443, 14.1402306532103, 
13.6308927640127)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

and the code
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


formula <- y ~ x
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = A,
           y = B)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = formula,
              se = TRUE) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson",
           show.legend = FALSE,
           cor.coef.name = "r",
           label.sep = "\n",
           label.x = 10,
           label.y = 12.6,
           size = 7) +
  theme_bw()



I do not have a solution, but I think the problem is located in the sep argument, e.g. the default is according to the documentation label.sep = ", ", however even with label.sep = "," the result looks the same. I.e. I suspect that the whitespace gets automatically inserted after the seperator no matter what you input in label.sep.

The issue is that stat_cor uses ?plotmath for the labels which does not allow for line breaks. Hence, when using label.sep="\n" it uses atop() to fake a line break which however center aligns the labels.
One option to fix that would be to create the labels via two separate calls to stat_cor:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

formula <- y ~ x
ggplot(
  data = df,
  aes(
    x = A,
    y = B
  )
) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_smooth(
    method = "lm",
    formula = formula,
    se = TRUE
  ) +
  stat_cor(
    aes(label = after_stat(r.label)),
    method = "pearson",
    show.legend = FALSE,
    cor.coef.name = "r",
    label.x = 10,
    label.y = 12.7,
    size = 7
  ) +
  stat_cor(
    aes(label = after_stat(p.label)),
    method = "pearson",
    show.legend = FALSE,
    cor.coef.name = "r",
    label.x = 10,
    label.y = 12.5,
    size = 7
  ) +
  theme_bw()



I think the problem is due to centering of the text at the specified position, which doesn't seem to be modifiable.
One hacky solution is to ensure that the number of digits is the same for both r and p.
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = A,
           y = B)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = formula,
              se = TRUE) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson",
           cor.coef.name = "r",
           label.x = 10,
           label.y = 12.6,
           label.sep = "\n",
           size = 7,
           r.accuracy = 0.001,   # <---- Here
           p.accuracy = 0.001) + # <---- Here
  theme_bw()


The vignette suggests using atop for two-line labels:
stat_cor(aes(label = paste("atop(", ..r.label.., ",", ..p.label.., ")", sep = "")), ...
But this doesn't seem to work either.
